# How to take desktop screenshot at any instance and converted into a pdf file?

Tags: apex

How to take desktop screenshot at any instance and converted into a pdf file?
For Example - I will have a button on the visualforce page on whose click the account's object limit page's screenshot should be taken and converted into a pdf file.

Answer (score 2):

The browser doesn't have access to take a full screen shot but if you want an image of the web page (i.e. it won't include the Windows task bar or anything else outside the webpage) you could have it read the DOM and try to render it on canvas.

Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

And this: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Once you have the image you could potentially AJAX it back to the server and have it forward on to a VF page with the renderAs="pdf" attribute.